Image doesn't show in Tikzposter
I'm using Tikzposter and when I've tried to add an image it doesn't show in the pdf, after compilation. I have used this code :
 \block{A figure}
    {
        \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/overleaf-logo}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Description of the figure}{\blindtext}

Could you help with a solution? I need to finish my poster.
Thanks a lot.
Ochaigbe

Welcome to TeX StackExchange! It's hard to tell what the problem is without more detail. Do you have an image file named overleaf-logo in a folder called images? Is there an error message? It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include this information.

Inside a tikzpicture everything except drawing commands is ignored. As far as TikZ is concerned \includegraphics{} is just more detritus. You will probably find a warning on the terminal/in the log warning you about this.
Either
\block{A figure} {% maybe in a `center` environment?
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/overleaf-logo}
} 
\column{0.5} 
\block{Description of the figure}{\blindtext} 

or
\block{A figure} {%
  \begin{tikzfigure} 
  \node {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/overleaf-logo}};
  \end{tikzfigure}%
} 
\column{0.5} 
\block{Description of the figure}{\blindtext} 

but this second is pointless unless you wish to draw something, too. So you should use the first if you simply want to include an image.
